# Parse without ignoring whitespaces - Java

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have the following string input (from a `netstat -a` command):

```
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11453    /run/systemd/shutdownd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7644     /run/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7646     /run/systemd/cgroups-agent
unix  5      [ ]         DGRAM                    7657     /run/systemd/journal/socket
unix  14     [ ]         DGRAM                    7659     /dev/log
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16620
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16621
```

Meanwhile I'm attempting to parse the above string as:

```
// lines is an array representing each line above
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    String[] tokens = lines[i].split("\\s+");
}
```

I want to have `tokens` as an array of 7 entries `[Proto, RefCnt, Flag, Type, State, I-Node, Path]`. Instead, I'm obtaining an array that excludes  the brackets under `Flags` and the empty `State`:

```
["unix", "2", "[", "]", "DGRAM", "11453", "/run/systemd/shutdownd"]
```

instead of

```
["unix", "2", "[]", "DGRAM", "", "11453", "/run/systemd/shutdownd"]
```

How can I fix my regex to produce the correct output?

Comment: Using lookarounds `(?<!\[)\\s+(?!\])`

Comment: @revo Even with lookarounds there's one value missing (for state, the array will be length 6 instead of 7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set minimal space length in your regular expression to 2, try split like this:

```
String[] tokens = lines[i].split("\\s{2,16}+");
```

Or like @revo suggests using lookarounds, like this:

```
String[] tokens = lines[i].split("(?<!\\[)\\s{2,16}+(?!\\])");
```

Comment: Alexander, There's one value missing, I'm getting the following output: `[unix, 2, [ ], DGRAM, 11453, /run/systemd/shutdownd]`. The correct value would be `[unix, 2, [ ], DGRAM, "", 11453, /run/systemd/shutdownd]`

Comment: @cybertextron You can add maximun space legth also, like this `{2,16}`